# How to dynamically create a ARRAY based on a AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

How do I dynamically create a array after getting a AJAX response ?

The variable `data.villages` is my response.

I loop over its value using the jQuery each function:

```
$.each(data.villages, function(key, value) { 

   //Here I have the 2 variables: value.id and value.name

   //Now I need to build a array where the value.id is the KEY and the content is name : value.name

  //After I need to create an array with all the arrays

});
```

My final array should look like this:

```
[ 234141 : [{ name: 'vila1', othervariable: 'othervalue' }] ]
```

**I need this to get the name value (or any other property) by knowing the ID....**

Can you also show me example on how to get this data by knowing the ID ?

Comment: Why not just use JSON to begin with?

Comment: That is an invalid array. Is it a kind of "associative array"?

Comment: Like Rob says, even if it "looks" like an array, it won't be. In JavaScript, arrays are zero-origin indexed, with the index built implicitly. JavaScript will treat your "array" as an object, so might as well make it an object. Then as per Diodeus, you could just be sending back the data object in JSON and you won't have to do any additional processing.

Answer (score 2):

To create an array of objects from your json response you should be able to do something like this:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [];

for (var i = 0, var dataLength = data.villages.length; i < dataLength; i++) {
      arrayOfObjects.push(data.villages[i]);
}
```

What I think you actually want is an object.  You can object like so:

```
var objectFromJson= {};

for (var i = 0, var dataLength = data.villages.length; i < dataLength; i++) {
      var currentItem = data.villages[i];
      objectFromJson[currentItem.WhatEverPropertyYouWantForTheKey] = currentItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your final array is wrong:

```
[ 234141 : [{ name: 'vila1', othervariable: 'othervalue' }] ]
```

must be:

```
[ 
    { 234141 : [{ name: 'vila1', othervariable: 'othervalue' }] }
]
```

that is, an array with an object with the id=234141 and value [{name: ....}]

You can achieve that with:

```
data.villages = "your returned data array";
var newArray = [ { 234141: [] } ];
$.each(data.villages, function(key, value) {
    newArray[0]['234141'].push({key: value};
}
```

Comment: Cool... but, I net to have the ID value (234141) also set dinamically... Can It be done ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like

```
arr = new Array();
arr[value.key] = {var1: 'vila1', var2: 'vila2'};
```

you are just storing json